# Paginating dots in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

**Context:**

We are developing an iOS application that implements a flipboard-esque functionality. It lists out a specific number of articles in a page and there could be any number of pages.

We are maintaining a **viewControllerStack** to store all such **viewControllers** (that has a specific number of articles).

To achieve this, we are using the `UIPageViewController` and it is working fine for us. When the page reaches the last page in the **viewControllerStack**, it makes a **REST** call to find if there are many more articles. If there are it will put in our stack and we can scroll ahead to see them.

**Problem:**

The number of dots in this PVC increasing and it is overflowing. If we limit the number of pages, the dots seem to be coming to the first page.

**Question:**

Is there any way that could limit this number of dots and yet be indicative to the user that there are more pages after and before, if there are?

Comment: There are various ways to intuitively indicate more pages.  One such way is to create a custom pager that includes an ellipses, some graphic, or even 'More...' at the end.  I probably wouldn't go with the standard pager for this case. Observe how websites, for example, behave with many pages of data and emulate that with a custom pager.

Comment: I wouldn't either. But I have been asked be use the standard pager to somehow make it intuitive. It's not in my hands, you see...

Comment: I think the answer to your question would be no then without making a custom pager.  If you are implementing flipboard-esque functionality, then I would say go the extra step to implement a flipboard-esque pager.